# Map a range of ports to another range of ports (equal lengths of ranges)

Tags: networking, ssh, iptables, firewall

In this answer, [How can I open a range of ports in ubuntu using (g)ufw](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7099/how-can-i-open-a-range-of-ports-in-ubuntu-using-gufw), a simple command for opening a range of ports is given.

For example, using this command I can open the ports 1000-1999 very easily for my firewall on my local machine.

Now, though, I would like to set-up port forwarding on the local machine, so that:

- Port 1001 forwards to port 1
- Port 1002 forwards to port 2
- Port 1003 forwards to port 3
- ... etc
  -

Does anyone have a simple bash script for doing this?

I have to do this for multiple machines on a local network. Constraints by the router are making this more difficult than it needs to be.

So machine A, ports 1000-1999 on the router would be opened to link to machine A. On machine A, they would be forwarded to the traditional port.  For machine B, ports 2000-2999 on the router would be used (mapped to the appropriate port locally). Etc

Comment: Please tell us exactly what you're trying to accomplish with all of this port forwarding. It sounds like you're making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I agree, but it has to do with the router's constraints. I can specify a range of ports to receive in the router, but only map within the router to "SAME" or "SINGLE" ports at the host -- I can't specify a range of ports to map from within the router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mostly Stolen from the Internet]

Enable IP forwarding:

`sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Use the "nat" table to forward traffic:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination X.X.X.X:80`

Don't forget about HTTPS:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination X.X.X.X:443
```

Ask iptables to masquerade:

```
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

....and if you want that for each port in a range, i suggest something alike:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 y=0;  //first port to map to = 1, but y++ happens before mapping, so 0
 for i in {2000..2999}
    do
       ((y++));  
       echo "forwarding port $i to port $y";
       iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport $i -j DNAT --to-destination X.X.X.X:$y;
 done
```

Note:

- system ports 1-1000 are reserved, so the above script is a bad idea
  ;)
- offcourse substitute X.X.X.X with localhost or wherever you want
  to nat-forward

Comment: But if I'm mapping TO 1-1000, then it doesn't matter?

Comment: no.. you cannot map to 1-1000 unless you know what you are doing. You should never map a range to 1-1000. 

ofc, if you want e.g. to map 8080 to 443 or 80, thats perfectly ok, but the <1000 ports are considered reserved and in most cases shouldn't be all mapped to.

check out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: Quote "The port numbers in the range from 0 to 1023 are the well-known ports or system ports.[2] They are used by system processes that provide widely used types of network services. On Unix-like operating systems, a process must execute with superuser privileges to be able to bind a network socket to an IP address using one of the well-known ports.[4]"

Comment: Oh right duh. i would disturb an underlying system process listening on that port.

Comment: would you mind accepting my answer @nickcarraway? :)